# Does localStorage.clear(); clear ALL from PC?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

If I call the following:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  localStorage.clear();
};
```

Does this clear all local storage from a user machine or just what my site has set?

Comment: Can you think of the problems it would cause if it emptied the storage set by any site?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but, I also don't want to start trashing other peoples data for no reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the spec for `clear`](https://w3c.github.io/webstorage/#dom-storage-clear):

> The clear() method must atomically cause the list associated with the object to be emptied of all key/value pairs, if there are any. If there are none, then the method must do nothing.

In the above, "the object" in this context would be `localStorage`.  What is `localStorage`?  From [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/webstorage/#dom-localstorage):

> The localStorage object provides a Storage object for an origin.

So, it will just clear out the data for your origin, or domain.